# Memory Usuage Between Data Types in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I'm trying to figure out why an int8 uses more memory than a float data type. Shouldn't it less since it should only be using 1 byte of memory.

```
import numpy as np
import sys

In [32]: sys.getsizeof(np.int8(29.200))
Out[32]: 25

In [33]: sys.getsizeof(np.int16(29.200))
Out[33]: 26

In [34]: sys.getsizeof(np.int32(29.200))
Out[34]: 28

In [35]: sys.getsizeof(np.float(29.200))
Out[35]: 24

In [36]: sys.getsizeof(np.float32(29.200))
Out[36]: 28

In [37]: sys.getsizeof(np.float64(29.200))
Out[37]: 32
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `getsizeof` on isolated `np.types` like this isn't very informative.

`np.int8(...)` is an object that includes not just the data byte, but various numpy attributes.  It's similar to a `np.array(123, dtype=int8)`.  In other words the array overhead is larger than the data storage itself.

It's more useful to look at the size of `np.ones((1000,), dtype=np.int8)` etc.  That `getsize` will have show the 1000 data bytes, plus an array 'overhead'.

```
In [31]: sys.getsizeof(np.int8(123))
Out[31]: 13
In [32]: sys.getsizeof(np.int16(123))   # 1 more byte
Out[32]: 14
In [33]: sys.getsizeof(np.int32(123))   # 2 more bytes
Out[33]: 16
In [34]: sys.getsizeof(np.int64(123))   # 4 more bytes
Out[34]: 24
In [35]: sys.getsizeof(123)
Out[35]: 14
```

For these arrays there's a 48 bytes overhead, and then 1000 elements:

```
In [36]: sys.getsizeof(np.ones(1000, np.int8))  # 1 byte each
Out[36]: 1048
In [37]: sys.getsizeof(np.ones(1000, np.int16))  # 2 bytes each
Out[37]: 2048

In [38]: np.ones(1000, np.int8).itemsize  # np.int8(123).itemsize
Out[38]: 1
In [39]: np.ones(1000, np.int16).itemsize
Out[39]: 2
```